# "Are you calling me a liar?"

Tags: rhetoric

Normally I ignore the formalisms of rhetoric, but I'm curious:

*When the question, “Are you calling me a liar?”, is used to “defend” a point of opinion or interpretation, would it best be classified as an ad hominem argument, or something else?*

Having just refused to play that game with someone, I'd like to know what flavor of trouble I dodged.

(In this case, it was a matter of someone having built up an incorrect memory of an event in order to justify having reacted inappropriately at the time. Not lying, not untruthful, simply mistaken, defensive, and trying to argue by assertion, intimidation, and emotion. I actually have some sympathy for their having painted themselves into a corner, but I'm not going to accept "because I said so".)

Comment: It may well be an *ad hominem* argument. Another might be to reply 'No, I merely infer that you are economical with the truth'.

Comment: In bars, taverns, and pubs, it constitutes an invitation to confirm that you want to get punched in the mouth.

Comment: It can probably be classified several different ways, depending on context, and depending on your personal classification system for rhetorical devices.  It is most certainly implying that the speaker views your mutual interaction as adverse.  The question is largely rhetorical -- the speaker may actually believe that you are falsely accusing him, but more likely he's indirectly accusing you of lying (whether he believes this or not), and he's trying to deflect your current arguing point.

Comment: @WS@: I think you mean to say "imply," not "infer." Since the person taking umbrage is doing so based on what the accused person SAID, from the perspective of the umbrage taker the accused person is, by implication, calling Mr. Umbrage a liar. True, in his reasoning process the accused may have concluded/inferred that Mr. Umbrage is a liar, but from his perspective Mr. Accused's implication constitutes "fightin' words"! Mr. Umbrage could just as easily have said, "Are you implying I'm a liar?"

Comment: I have edited your question to include the key phrase. A question should be complete in itself and not require reference to the title (which may or may not be "above"). I have also lightly emphasized it as one new user seems to have missed the fact there was a question buried in your account of a personal experience.

Answer (score 3):

No it would not best be described as *ad hominem*, as it is not attacking you at all. It isn't even making a statement, as it is asking a question.

The best description of this fallacy (assuming you did not call actually call the other a liar) would be a **Red Herring**.  The other guy is shifting the grounds of the discussion from the original argument to a new one that is presumably easier to defend.

If you think the accusation was merely outrage at being disagreed, then the closest fallacy to that would be **argument from authority**.  He is considering himself the authority in question that must be accepted ipso facto.

Comment: That's plausible. Let's see what else is suggested, but I'm currently inclined to accept this one as closest to what I was looking for.

Comment: If you search for "argument fallacies" there are several nice lists out there with definitions that can help out as well.

Answer (score 2):

The "formalisms of rhetoric" can be a pain in the tuches, to be sure. Kind of like the Latin names for flowers and trees and diseases and so on. They can be helpful, however, whenever you're interested in spicing up your communication with little rhetorical flourishes here and there. Some people may use them simply to impress others, and that's OK. A better use for them is to achieve better precision, as well as memorability. A good metaphor, analogy, or other figure or trope can help people better remember what you say.

As for the "Are you calling me a liar?" locution, it most definitely can be voiced in a  bellicose manner! I wouldn't call the locution an ad hominem, however; rather, I'd call it a *reaction to* a *perceived* or *inferred* ad hominem (i.e., an attack against the person and his character). Rather than being a rhetorical figure or trope, it is probably better described as evidence of a truculent disposition or temperament. Some folks are overly sensitive to a perceived insult. A simple and innocent "Are you sure about that?" can elicit a "Are you calling me a liar?" from them in a nanosecond!

Comment: Hm. Perhaps rhetoric doesn't have a term for it, but I would still like to find a good label for argument-from-outrage-at-being-disagreed-with, simply as a tool for recognizing, avoiding, and deflecting that pattern. I might need to go to the jargon used for classifying marketing and propaganda to find the right word.

Comment: outrage at being disagreed with is a kind of *argument from authority*, with the other considering himself the authority.  In my opinion.

Comment: @oldcat: That's also plausible. If you make that an Answer, I'd give it an up-vote.

Comment: added it to my other answer.

Comment: @keshlam: The "Are you calling me a liar" locution is also a deflection of sorts. The speaker is deflecting and at the same time defusing a perceived attack on his credibility. Aristotle's word for credibility is ethos, which is how an audience perceives your intelligence, virtue, and good will. The question ("Are you calling . . .") is a perceived attack on one's virtue, an important element of ethos. The attack can be countered in a civilized manner by, for example, shoring up one's perceived virtue with a powerful anecdote highlighting one's truthfulness, which is crucial to good ethos.

Answer (score 1):

In an argument between debaters where observers are judging the outcome, this might be called **poisoning the well**, describe in *[Logically Fallacious](http://www.logicallyfallacious.com/index.php/logical-fallacies/141-poisoning-the-well)* by Bo Bennett  (and also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well)):

> To commit a preemptive ad hominem attack against an opponent.  That is, to prime the audience with adverse information about the opponent from the start, in an attempt to make your claim more acceptable, or discount the credibility of your opponent’s claim.

One could say that, by making the accusation about lying before responding to the argument that has been made, the well has been poisoned, and diverts attention away from a weak direct response.

Related is the **[just because I say so](http://www.logicallyfallacious.com/index.php/logical-fallacies/116-just-because-fallacy)** or **[appeal to authority](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/appeal-to-authority.html)** fallacy, which apply even when there are no outside observers to the debate. These are described by Bennett thus:

> Refusing to respond to give reasons or evidence for a claim by stating yourself as the ultimate authority in the matter... “Just because” is not a reason that speaks to the question itself; it is simply a deflection to authority (legitimate or not).

---

It can also be described with some of the more fundamental terms of rhetoric.

**Ignoring the issue** (*ignoratio elenchi*) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoratio_elenchi)) is a catchall for many debate tactics, including this one, where the speaker is **changing the subject** to "Let's talk about what you think about ME" instead of "Here is where you are wrong about what I said".

Your example is a peculiar one, because it might be taken to implicitly accuse the opponent of being the one who changed the subject.

It also becomes a bald face **appeal to emotion** (*pathos*) over credibility and logic (*ethos* and *logos*) when the object of the debate is to sway observers.  Pathos, ethos, and logos are referred to as the *modes of persuasion*, recognized by [Aristotle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_of_persuasion) in his *On Rhetoric*.

This is clearly an attempt to flip the switch from *ethos* and *logos* to *pathos*

So you might consider this to be a **pathetic attempt to change the subject**. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is instructive to examine the common precursor to the question "Are you calling me a liar?"  Often, this question results from the antagonist relying on anecdotal evidence to prove his or her point. The conversation often goes like this:

P1: Banning homework is a bad idea.
P2: I banned homework and my students are doing much better. What do you say to that?!?!
P1: How do I know your anecdote is true?
P2: Are you calling me a liar?

At this point, P1 is boxed into a corner. He has to either call P2 a liar or concede the point. This scheme allows anyone to win an argument by concocting personal anecdotes that support their position. It is especially effective if the two people already have a personal relationship.

I have found that even the most faithfully honest people will lie or exaggerate in order to win a debate. This is why I never trust personal anecdotes.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. This is a Question and Answer site, not a discussion site. There is a question buried in @keshlam's post — "would it be best classified as an ad hominem argument, or something else?" Your "answer" does not provide an answer to this question. Please take the guided tour and learn how to [answer questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Answers that don't conform may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).